# Which php binary should be used with a XAMPP installation?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, unix, xampp

When I execute `which php` in Bash I get `/usr/bin/php`. Everything is working fine but I'm wondering - since I'm running XAMPP, should I get `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` instead?

Note: I'm using OSX 10.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/usr/bin/php mean it's php default installed on macos, for xampp it should be on /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin. if you want use php version from xampp, you can disabled /usr/bin/php and make symlink /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php to /usr/bin/php.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using XAMPP's own php binary instead of the one of the OS?

Comment: if you develop and tested using XAMPP, better using XAMPP version, because it could be php version/setting different. sometimes xampp version and macos one include different php modules.

Comment: Aren't PHP modules separate files?

Comment: yes,you're right. but when you execute php, it will loaded the modules that you enabled on php setting.